How to refer to Enum in Spring @Cacheable Annotation
I have a Spring Boot project where I want to implement caching for results returned to me by the remote endpoints that I am addressing. However, I don't just want to cache everything, but only under certain conditions.
Specifically, I am addressing an endpoint that returns me a result object containing an enum detailing whether the request was successful or not. I want to cache that result, but only if the result was successful.
In normal code, I would simply check this with a condition like:
if(result.status == MyStatus.OK)

However, this doesn't work in the @Cacheable annotation. I know it needs to go into the "unless" parameter, but when I try to enter an equivalent of above condition in there like this for example...
@Cacheable(value = 'myCacheName',
        key = "#myKey",
        unless = "#result.status() != MyStatus.OK")

...I only get an error "Cannot resolve class 'MyStatus'".
Is this somehow possible at all? If yes, how do I need to write this?

Short answer:
@Cacheable(value = 'myCacheName',
        key = "#myKey",
        unless = "#result.status() != T(com.my_service.MyStatus).OK")

There are two things you need to do in order to enable the SpEL (Spring Expression Language) to find the class in question:

Enclose the class name in a T()
Use the class's fully qualified name

